# RDD functions such as parallelize and textFile not available in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I installed `SparkR` library on my local Mac Os from the following git repo-

```
devtools::install_github('apache/spark@v1.5.0', subdir='R/pkg').
```

I see [examples of `sparkR` code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/pkg/R/backend.R) which use Spark functions such as `parallelize` and `textFile`. However, when I tried the same, it gave me the following error:

> Error: could not find function "textFile"

How can I use these functions in `sparkR` code?

Answer (score 2):

These functions are no longer exported. If necessary, they are still accessible
via

```
SparkR:::textFile
```

Comment: Thanks Wannes. When i tried this, I got Error: 'textFile' is not an exported object from 'namespace:SparkR'.

Comment: From where have you installed SparkR?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html from source code. Remark that you should use three :, when you only use 2, he will be searching for it as an exported object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was missing the third :.